# Counting occurrences of elements from data stream

Tags: approximation, data-analysis

Suppose I have a data stream, and I need to **approximate** the count the number of occurrences of each element.

I have already read about data streaming algorithms especially **estimating the number of distinct elements**, I have come to conclusion that counting occurrences of elements in a data stream might be a generalization of the distinct elements problem.

I would appreciate if ideas/approaches of how may I generalize the distinct element problem, or can suggest some papers that might help with counting occurrences of elements?

Comment: You want to approximately count the number of occurrences of each element. What are you trying to optimize for (compared to exact counting)? Streaming counting algorithms optimize for storage size, since recording the exact number of distinct elements means every element has to be recorded. Counting the number of occurrences of each element doesn't seem like it would have the same storage problems.

Comment: Obtaining the exact value is a good approximation. I don't think your question can really be answered in any other fashion unless your data or your application have specific features that would allow it.

Comment: @jwg, Yes I need to approximate the number of occurrences of each element while using at most `O(log(n)` space when n is the number of elements.

Comment: But what does approximate mean? Are counts for log(n) elements an approximation to counts for all elements? Or do you need a count for each element, but they can afford to be inaccurate? How to decide between these two might depend on the distribution of the counts.

Comment: @Hurkyl I did not get that why obtaining the exact value is a good approximation? what about space ? can you please elaborate, let's suppose that my data is IP addresses and my goal is to prevent a DDoS attack.

Comment: let's suppose that my data stream is numbers between `1 and n`, my goal is to approximately estimate the number of occurrences of a given number while using maximum space of `O(log(n)` . I hope I explained myself well.

Comment: @JayMar: Keeping in mind I don't know anything about how network security works, it sounds like your data has the interesting features that **(1)** You only care about the elements appearing with high frequency, **(2)** You might be able to bin network addresses; e.g. as ###.###.###.*, and **(3)** You have an extra problem you haven't even noticed: you need to age off old data.

Comment: No, you didn't explain yourself well. 1. Do you want a count for every number, but they can all be quite inaccurate? Or are you happy to only have a count for around log(n) elements (for example the most commonly used), with all the rest being ignored? 2. How are the numbers distributed? Do all appear around the same amount (which makes the task harder)? Or do some appear much more than others (which means it might be reasonable to approximate counts of these to 0)?

Comment: @jwg The goal is counting occurrences  for every number, but I can afford inaccuracy, regarding the second question, there's no assumptions or prior knowledge about the data being streamed.

Comment: Then it's very hard to see a solution. To count n items, even extremely inaccurately, it seems like you probably need O(n) storage. Otherwise how could you recall the n items you counted?